# Force widgets in column to match largest

Tags: flutter, dart

I have several RaisedButton widgets inside of a column, and they have different widths based on their texts. I would like them to be the same width, but I do not want to set a static width, as it should be able to respond to changes in language and screen size/shape. The smaller widget should be resized to match the width of the largest widget in the column. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks!

```
Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                      child: Text("Btn1"),
                      onPressed: (){},
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                      child: Text("LongerBtn2"),
                      color: Colors.Red,
                      onPressed: (){},
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Could do this:

```
        IntrinsicWidth( // <- Sizes its child's width to the child's maximum intrinsic width
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, // <- all children will try to take as much space as possible 
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Btfffffff fsdfds dsfsa n1"),
                color: Colors.green,
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("LongerBtn2"),
                color: Colors.red,
                onPressed: () {},
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
```